# Why my items in jquery ui is not updated when i remove it

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have problem with jquery ui autocomplete remove,

i'm unable to remove selected item for next iteration.

**Question:** i want remove selected item on each export and `availableTags` should be bound to `$("#tags")` autocomplete so, i will get all  tags at any time except, permanently exported one.

**Note:** i'm following this approach as i will be having more than `50000`  `tags`

**here is my code:**

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [

  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    availableTags.push('abc' + i);
  }
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);

      response(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
  }).focus(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete('search');
  });

  $('#exportPer').click(function() {
    var pExp = $('#tags').val();
    console.log('permanently exported tag : ', pExp + '  , it wont be availabe in list');
    var placeholderList = $("#tags").autocomplete("option", "source");

    var index = placeholderList.indexOf(pExp);

    console.log('spliced', placeholderList.splice(index, i));


  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


<div style="margin-top: -22px; margin-right: 79px; float: right;">
  <button id="exportPer">Export Permanantely</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `placeholderList.indexOf` is not a function

Comment: @mplungjan, actually i'm expecting when you click `export permanently` button that  tag should not be availabe in `autocomplete` input  when he tries to do it 2nd time.

Comment: So you need to remove it from the source and refresh the autocomplete which is not what you seem to be doing now

Comment: @mplungjan, yes but refresh , i meant to say `availableTags` should not be available in `autocomplete`

Comment: what happned if abc1 and abc2 both are exported one by one, will it display in the auto search or not ??

Comment: See my answer - it can handle one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the tag from the list and make the tags global

```js
var availableTags = [];

function listTags(request, response) {
  var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
  response(results.slice(0, 10));
}

$(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    availableTags.push('abc' + i);
  }
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: listTags
  }).focus(function() {
    $("#tags").autocomplete('search');
  });

  $('#exportPer').click(function() {
    var pExp = $('#tags').val();
    var index = availableTags.indexOf(pExp);
    if (index !=-1) {
      availableTags.splice(index, 1);
      console.log('permanently exported tag : ', pExp + '  , it wont be availabe in list');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


<div style="margin-top: -22px; margin-right: 79px; float: right;">
  <button id="exportPer">Export Permanantely</button>
</div>
```